# Dynamic assets in Nuxt / vite

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, require, vite

I can load images dynamically from a folder in Nuxt (+ webpack) simply with a method like:

```
getServiceIcon(iconName) {
  return require ('../../static/images/svg/services/' + iconName + '.svg');
}
```

I moved to Vite, and `require` is not defined here (using rollup). How can I solve this, with nuxt / vite? Any idea?

Comment: You're using Nuxt3? https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/868

Comment: Nope, 2.15.8. Ty, looking into it tho.

Comment: Then, you can maybe ask your question down in the related repo: https://github.com/nuxt/vite/issues?q=is%3Aissue+images+

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `import()` like this:

```js
const getServiceIcon = async iconName => {
  const module = await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `../../static/images/svg/services/${iconName}.svg`)
  return module.default.replace(/^\/@fs/, '')
}
```

[demo 1: Vue 3 Composition API](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-glob-imports?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FIconSelect.vue)

[demo 2: Vue 3 Options API](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-glob-imports-zvu5l1?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FIconSelect.vue)

[demo 3: Vue 2 Composition API](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-glob-imports-fyc874?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FIconSelect.vue)

[demo 4: Vue 2 Options API](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-glob-imports?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Facing this error - `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module`