# Dynamically loading SVG in Vue3 and Vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to convert my Vue2/Webpack app to Vue3/Vite.

In Vue2/Webpack, this works:

```
<div v-html="require('!!html-loader!../../assets/icons/' + this.icon + '.svg')"></div>
```

Html-loader is added with:

```
"html-loader": "1.3.2",
```

In Vue3/Vite this throws the error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I've looked around for an example of doing this but don't see how to do this without knowing the name of the file at compile time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use *Lazy Load Components* technique with `defineAsyncComponent` from `Vue3` - [ref.](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0026-async-component-api.md)

or `import()` like is shown by @tony19 in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837637/dynamic-assets-in-nuxt-vite):

```
<script>
const getServiceIcon = async iconName => {
  const module = await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `../assets/svg/${iconName}.svg`)
  return module.default.replace(/^\/@fs/, '')
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      icon: null,
      iconName: 'icon1', // icon1.svg
    }
  },
  watch: {
    iconName: {
      async handler(iconName) {
        this.icon = await getServiceIcon(iconName)
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="iconName = 'icon2'">Change to another SVG</button>
  <img :src="icon" height="72" width="72" />
</template>
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I am on a quest to use as few third party plugins as possible, and use only svg.  Used this to create a component to replace zondicons, just changig the watcher to mounted.  (never liked the heroicon method of one component for each icon...).  thx / mike

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at [vite-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader) plugin, and  load SVG files as Vue components.

Answer (score 4):

Simply by creating a component where you will load the icons. Using composition API here.

```
<template>
    <i v-html="svg" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue';

    const props = defineProps(['icon', 'src']);
    const path = props.src ? props.src : '';
    const file = `${path}icon-${props.icon}`;
    const modules = import.meta.glob('../../assets/icons/**/*.svg', { as: 'raw' });

    const svg = computed(() => {
        return modules['../../assets/icons/' + file + '.svg'];
    });
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

This will allow you to even style your SVG using css, tailwind etc...

The usage:

```
<UiIcon icon="NAME" class="w-8 fill-current text-red-500"/>
```

Done.