# Nuxt+Tailwind: background-image with arbitrary values

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

While creating a project on the Nuxt + Tailwind stack, I stumbled upon another problem.
Following the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image) I wanted to add a background image, but css does not display it (other Tailwind classes work)

****.vue**

```
<div class="bg-[url('img/stories/desktop/18-days-voyage.jpg')]">
  <h3>The Mountains</h3>
  <p>by John Appleseed</p>
  <a href="/6">Read story</a>
</div>
```

However, if I am use the img tag with the same path to the image, then it displays.

```
<img src="img/stories/desktop/18-days-voyage.jpg" alt="" />
```

Need to make the first way work. Can you tell me where to dig? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I copied your code, and directly paste on my nuxt project with img directory in root location. Its working fine. Please check the directory clearly.

Comment: I would like to clarify. My pictures are arranged like this **'./static/img/__'**, and in the code I write like this **'/img/__'**. Do you also? @MdRathik

Comment: Maybe try `:class="bg-[url(require('img/stories/desktop/18-days-voyage.jpg'))]"` as shown in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets#images). You could also try to set it into a state and reference it there (like in a `computed()`). Maybe also try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69865828/8816585).